# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodes' of null(…)

Tags: javascript, three.js

Try to load .dae file with treejs but i got js error in my console which refer to these lines in [THREE.ColladaLoader](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/ColladaLoader.js#L167-L171):

```
for ( var i = 0; i < visualScene.nodes.length; i ++ ) {

  scene.add( createSceneGraph( visualScene.nodes[ i ] ) );

}
```

i downloaded all of three js dev branch and no chance even dev branch example warn me with above error any idea ?

Comment: `visualScene` is null. Check where you're getting/setting the data for it.

Comment: This looks like the `THREE.ColladaLoader` couldn't properly parse your file. Can you post your `.dae`-file somewhere for reference? Or maybe try if the `THREE.ColladaLoader2` (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/ColladaLoader2.js, and no, I don't know why there are two of them) has better results?

Comment: Thank you for response, but i test monster.dae which exist on mrdoob repository. even i download all of test files about .dae file and examples from threejs repo, but i got this error this mean repository example has error but why!